# Sending logs using log4j to web service in Java

Tags: java, web-services, log4j, appender

I am fairly new to the web services world but have knowledge of `log4j`.

I need to implement a functionality which will send the log messages to a web service rather than to a file using **web service appender**.

I read by searching on **Google** that `WebServiceAppender` is one of the `log4j` class, but I couldn't verify this.

```
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=main.WSAppender 
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.endpoint=http://localhost:8080/Logging/services/logging?w‌​sdl 
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%p [%t] %c{2} (%M:%L) :: %m%n 
WSAppender.java extends AppenderSkeleton, can't resolve endpoint, hostname in append()    

if (endpoint == null) { 
    System.out.println("no endpoint set. Check configuration file"); 
    System.out.println("[" + hostname + "] " + this.layout.format(event)); 
    return; 
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code you've tried to use so far? You're going to need to first show some research on this if you want some help. With some code, it will give us some place to start instead of implementing this for you. Tell us where you are stuck. Your only other hope is if someone comes along who knows this inside and out and is willing to post a full solution. Good luck!

Comment: Hi dulcet, your comment to Craig makes me think you should take this a step at a time. What error messages are you getting? How far did you get in the resource link. The more details you provide, the easier it will be to help, and the better answers you'll get. Hope this helps!

Comment: I am guessing that the log4j.properties file is not getting picked up, I have used axis2 implementation in eclipse and can see the file already present. So I added the above to it. Basically endpoint needs to be picked from somewhere, as the error message says the obvious, `endpoint` cannot be resolved to a variable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when you extend the class `AppenderSkeleton` I would assume that you should initialize your webservice class in the `public void activateOptions()` method which you should override. I've written DatabaseAppender and JmsAppender log4j loggers and I've always found that I have to initialize the db connection or jms connection or in your case the webservice properties in the `public void activateOptions()` method.

Then as usual in the `append(LoggingEvent)` method you would just invoke the webservice.

Might I suggest to implement a BlockingQueue to store all the LoggingEvent objects so that if you are getting an influx of log messages they are queued and sent to the webservice asynchronously.

**Updated to include a Template Log4j Class**

Try to use the below template. I added comments in important sections. Basically in the activateOptions and processEvent method is where you would initialize your "connection" and send your event objects. Can be DB, JMS, WebService ...etc.

```
package mypackage;

      import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
      import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
      import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
      import org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton;
      import org.apache.log4j.helpers.LogLog;
      import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;

      public class WebServiceAppender extends AppenderSkeleton {

            private static final BlockingQueue<LoggingEvent> loggingEventQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<LoggingEvent>();
            private static WebServiceAppender instance;
            private static Thread thread = null;

            //Your custom properties for your web service

            private String property1;
            private String property2;
            private String property3;

            static {
                thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        processQueue();
                    }
                });

                thread.setDaemon(true);
                thread.start();
            }

            private static void processQueue() {
                while(true) {
                    try {
                        LoggingEvent event = loggingEventQueue.poll(1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                        if (event != null) {
                            instance.processEvent(event);
                        }
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException e) {
                        // No operations.
                    }
                }
            }

            private final void processEvent(LoggingEvent loggingEvent) {
                if(loggingEvent != null) {
                    //Send the loggingEvent object or you can
                    //get data out of it and package it in another
                    //java class and send that, to your web service.

                    //Web Service is invoked here
                }
            }

            public synchronized void close() {
                // The synchronized modifier avoids concurrent append and close operations

                    if(this.closed) {
                      return;
                }

                closeWS();
                thread.interrupt();

                LogLog.debug("Closing appender [" + name + "].");
                this.closed = true;
            }

            private void closeWS() {
                try {
                    //Close the webservice connection 
                    //or whatever here.
                }
                catch(Exception ex) {
                    LogLog.error("Error while closing WebServiceAppender [" + name + "].", ex);
                }
            }

            public boolean requiresLayout() {
                //Does not need a layout because
                //we are sending serialized events
                //to an external source
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void activateOptions() {
                instance = this;
                try {
                    LogLog.debug("Getting web service properties.");

                    if(property1 != null) {
                        //Do something with your property
                    }

                    if(property2 != null) {
                        //Do something with your property
                    }

                    if(property3 != null) {
                        //Do something with your property
                    }

                    //Initialize your web-service connection and objects here
                    LogLog.debug("Web Service created.");
                }
                catch(Exception ex) {
                    LogLog.error("Error while activating options for WebServiceAppender [" + name + "].", ex);
                }
            }

            /*
             * These methods are set from the log4j properties file like:
             * log4j.appender.WS=mypackage.WebServiceAppender
             * log4j.appender.WS.property1=bla
             * log4j.appender.WS.property2=ble
             * log4j.appender.WS.property3=blo
             */

            public final String getProperty1() {
                return property1;
            }

            public final String getProperty2() {
                return property2;
            }

            public final String getProperty3() {
                return property3;
            }

            public final void setProperty1(String property1) {
                this.property1 = property1;
            }

            public final void setProperty2(String property2) {
                this.property2 = property2;
            }

            public final void setProperty3(String property3) {
                this.property3 = property3;
            }

            @Override
            protected void append(LoggingEvent event) {
                loggingEventQueue.add(event);
            }

            @Override
            public void finalize() {
                close();
                super.finalize();
            }
      }
```

Comment: this helps, but I am new to Queue and will try to learn and implement what you suggested. Also I was wondering if the `JMSAppender` can be used to send logs to the web service

Comment: Probably not, JMSAppender just sends the logs to a JMS topic via a JMS connection. If you want I can update my answer and include the code with stubs for making a custom appender.

Comment: Many thanks for the code, this will help me build the app quickly!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you have a look at this article: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-log4j/index.html

It specifically describes using the WebServiceAppender.

Ah, Google!

Comment: Thanks @craigmj, I checked this article very first thing, but I am getting confused, as there are code snippets, and being new I am getting lost as to where put all pieces

Comment: Hi craig, while this link may be helpful, if the link were to ever break, your answer would be useless. The best answers on Stack Overflow contain examples and explanation that not only help the original asker, but that also help many future visitors for years to come. Please consider making an [edit] to improve your answer. This will not just help others, but it will also get you more upvotes! Good luck! :)

Comment: Hi @jmort253, that's a good point. But short of copying the entire DeveloperWorks article, how might one approach the problem? (because in this case, the DW article is quite detailed...)

Comment: @craigmj, In this case, I think you do sort of have a point. It might be the best you can do without more details, which is why I haven't tried to edit myself. I'm hoping that dulcet can edit the question to something more specific, which would lead to a more specific answer and not be something he already tried. The question leans slightly into "not a real question" territory. Thanks for trying to help! ;)