# Exposing Log4j Logging Levels as rest webservice

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, log4j

Currently we are using log4j features for one of our module where admin users can view and download the logs, as per their roles defined , and based on the various selected logging levels **(info, debug, warning , fatal, error and trace)** - as per checkbox selection for each / all, he can generate the output of log file.

Hence, Needed to know how we can expose and consume various log4j Logging Levels as rest web services, which is getting logged in a database.

I have searched / googled all over the net with regard to how to proceed but unluckily no success till yet.

Would be grateful if any one can provide any pointers / suggestions / code for the same.

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried to do so far?

Comment: Hi @SimY4 .. Thanks for the reply..As of now I have created a model class for logging levels (info , warn , debug, error , fatal and trace) and its related service class (public LogLevel getLogLevel(String debug , String info , String warn , String error , String fatal , String trace) ;) and implementation class with a common interface. Accordingly I have created applicationContext.xml , cxf-servlet.xml and web.xml under the webapp - WEB-INF folder. But when I am deploying it on tomcat the static message from jsp page is getting displayed but not the wsdl file. plz suggest ..

Comment: By "showing" I don't mean "describing" it. Attach your code to the body of your question so we can help you. IMO, the main problem here is that you don't know how to create web services. On topic how to cunsume various logs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967508/sending-logs-using-log4j-to-web-service-in-java - this might be helpful